# Mathematical formulae for Complex Arcus Cotangents?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I'm writing reusable complex functions for use in Shaders.

I've done most of the complex series. All sines, cosines, and tangents (arcus, hyperbolic, and hyperbolic arcus variations as well)

However, I'm missing the last 2 arcus cotangents. I couldn't find any documentation on the function's definitions.

All I have is the complex cotangent and hyperbolic definitions, which are both pretty simple and obvious.

The Complex Arcus functions dont follow the same rules, so I dont know the definitions.

**(All c Functions are complex functions)**

$Complex\space Cotangent\left(z\right)=cDiv\left(cCos\left(z\right),\ cSin\left(z\right)\right)$

$Complex\space Hyperbolic\space Cotangent\left(z\right)=cDiv\left(cCosH\left(z\right),\ cSinH\left(z\right)\right)$

For example, here's the definition of the Complex Arcus Tangent: (Complex log uses base e)

$Complex\space Arcus\space Tangent\left(z\right)=cDiv\left(cLog\left(cMul\left(z,\ 1i\right)+1\right)-cLog\left(cMul\left(z,\ 1i\right)-1\right),\ 2i\right)$

It's very different from the typical `sin / cos = tan` rule

TL;DR: Im trying to find both of the Complex Arcus Cotangent and Complex Hyperbolic Arcus Cotangent

Comment: Have you looked on Wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions

Comment: Does $Mul(a,b)=ab,Div(a,b)=\frac ab$? If so, use \cdot and \frac{}{} etc

Comment: @TymaGaidash I typed them out specifically because they're complex functions, hence the c in front of every function.

Comment: @TomKern Those are traditional functions, not complex functions

Comment: @MisterSirCode In that case, what are the definitions of $cMul$ and $cDiv$? Ordinary multiplication ($\cdot$) also works for complex numbers, but with a few rules on how it is used. Also, this [paper on the complex trigonometric functions](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/archives/physics116A10/arc_10.pdf) has arccot, the “traditional one”, and Arccot, defined with the slightly different Ln, not ln, function. Are these the “complex arcus” functions you mean?

Comment: @MisterSirCode - TomKern's link does consider complex functions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Extension_to_complex_plane

Comment: @TymaGaidash Complex multiplication is definitely not the same. The only complex function that is identical to a standard function is addition and subtraction. That's common knowledge.

Comment: @mr_e_man I figured everything out, thanks. That page did have what I needed, I didnt look hard enough I suppose.